# Is this user spamming by promoting their own library?

Tags: discussion, spam, self-promotion

I've noticed that most of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3380739/user-3380739) user's answers reference [their library](https://github.com/landawn/AbacusUtil). Their answers aren't very thorough either; they are typically in this format:

> Try my library AbacusUtil:
>
> code snippet...

In addition, they typically don't provide any alternatives. Since this person discloses their affiliation with the library, is this considered spam or self-promotion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is an excessive recommendation of the user's library. User's are allowed to reference and link their work within their profile, but are not supposed to gratuitously link their work in their posts.

[**How to not be a spammer**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

> Don't talk about your product / website / book / job too much. Folks
>   will read your answers for their ability to solve a specific problem;
>   if you're good at doing that, then they'll find themselves more
>   interested in who you are and what you're working on. If you respond
>   only to questions where the answer can be something you're selling,
>   they'll assume you're just here to sell.

A mod flag on one of the posts explaining the over use of the links will help rectify this.

I've made a custom mod flag and left a comment for the OP.

[How can I convert a 1D list into a 2D list with Java Streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44599036/how-can-i-convert-a-1d-list-into-a-2d-list-with-java-streams/44599525#comment76187700_44599525)

> Please stop promoting your work in posts
>   https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion Also you are being discussed
>   here
>   [Is this user spamming by promoting their own library?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350859/is-this-user-spamming-by-promoting-their-own-library)

Comment: I think the key thing that needs to be noted here is that while it is okay to link to your library one or twice, its fine, as long as you disclose as such, bu if you're doing it for nearly all of your posts then it's spam.

Comment: @angussidney yes